# Finding number of strings possible

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the six letter alphabet: {A, B, C, D, E, F }.

(a). How many strings of length 15 have exactly 2 A’s, 3 B’s, 4 D’s, and 6 F’s?

(b). Of the strings described in part (b), how many have all 2 A’s before the 3 B’s?

For part (a), I got an answer by using $15 \choose 2$ * $13 \choose 3$ * $10 \choose 4$ *$6 \choose 6$

However, I am stuck on part B.

Answer (score 3):

So for part (a) we could have gone straight in with a multinomial coeffient.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{15}{2,3,4,6}.
\end{eqnarray*}
To do part (b) group all the $A$'s and $B$'s into one set of size $5$ and we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{15}{5,4,6}.
\end{eqnarray*}
When an element from this $5$-set is chosen, record an $A$ for the first two choices and $B$ for the others.

Answer (score 1):

Almost stars and bars: we have 5 bars and 10 stars, say: $$**A*A***B**B*B*$$ But then for each configuration of stars you should put instead of them $4$ $C $ and 6 $D$, so the answer is $${15\choose 5}\cdot {10!\over  4!\cdot 6!}$$